# How to avoid error in vba code last active sheet when it's deleted?

Tags: excel, vba

I run into an issue when deleting a sheet in my Excel file that has below code.

To jump to the previously selected sheet, I have below basic vba code in ThisWorkbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Set LstSht = Sh
End Sub
```

Below code is added in a module, and linked to a button to go back to the previous sheet.

```
Public LstSht As Worksheet
Sub GoToLast()
    LstSht.Activate
End Sub
```

I have noticed that there is no issue when I create a new sheet with the "+" button at the bottom in Excel, next to the already existing sheets. However, when I press the windows button + F11 to create a new Chart sheet, and delete this one, I receive a run-time error '13': Type mismatch.

How could this issue be resolved?

Thanks for your help!

Kind regards
Jan

Comment: This code doesn't give me any errors when I test it in a new workbook. What is the exact error and which line is highlighted when you click debug?

Comment: The code doesn't run into an error, but if you later use `LstSht` (a global var, I assume?), you will get an automation error.

Comment: I guess it would help if you would explain what you want to do with `LstSht`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, have added additional info in the problem description.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh Is LstSht Then
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count > 1 Then
            Set LstSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        Else
            Set LstSht = Nothing
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In this code, we first determine whether the deactivated sheet (Sh) and LstSht are same. If they are identical, we check to see if there are still other sheets in the workbook. If so, we use ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count) to set LstSht to the final sheet. Otherwise, we set LstSht to Nothing if there is only one sheet left or none at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your code indicates that you want to have a reference to the previous active sheet. But if this is deleted, this reference must become Nothing so that in other parts of the code it is checked and not used. This can be done in conjunction with one more event:

Copy the next code in a module (for common use)

```vb
Option Explicit

Public justDeactivatedSheet As Worksheet 'the variable you name LstSht
Public justDeletedSheet As Worksheet
```

Copy the next code in the ThisWorkBook module:

```vba
Option Explicit

'ON SHEET DELETION THIS IS EXECUTING FIRST
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDelete(ByVal Sh As Object)
   Set justDeletedSheet = Sh
   MsgBox ("Workbook_SheetBeforeDelete " & Sh.Name)
End Sub

'ON SHEET DELETION THIS IS EXECUTING AFTER Workbook_SheetBeforeDelete
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
   If Not justDeletedSheet Is Nothing Then
      If justDeletedSheet Is Sh Then
         MsgBox ("deactivate the deleted >" & vbCrLf & _
                 "Set justDeactivatedSheet = Nothing" & vbCrLf & _
                 "Set justDeletedSheet = Nothing")
         Set justDeactivatedSheet = Nothing
         Set justDeletedSheet = Nothing
      Else
         Set justDeactivatedSheet = Sh
      End If
   Else
      Set justDeactivatedSheet = Sh
   End If
End Sub
```

and copy an example of using the justDeactivatedSheet,
in a sheet's module. In my example i use a button's click event

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'in your code have to check, eg
   If Not justDeactivatedSheet Is Nothing Then
      If Not ActiveSheet Is justDeactivatedSheet Then
         MsgBox ("the previus active sheet was the " _
                  & justDeactivatedSheet.Name)
      End If
   Else
      MsgBox ("The justDeactivatedSheet is NOTHING ")
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This does look like it should work, but strangely enough it runs into the same issue...?

Comment: @Jan V You cannot use justDeactivatedSheet (yours LstSht) without first checking if it is not Nothing.